# AvailableFreeSpace always 0. Permission issue?

Tags: asp.net, linux, permissions, mono

I run a mono-xsp4 (asp.net) server on linux. My C# code:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo("/");
di.AvailableFreeSpace // always 0
di.TotalFreeSpace // Correct value
```

When I Put "main on" (mount drive again with other permissions) it works well. But i dont have these permissions normally.

Anybody with a workaround ?

thanks :)

Comment: try running the code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.100).aspx.  I'm wondering if `/` is not a valid drive name, since technically it's a mount point.  You may need to use `sda1` or something like that.  Run the script in the link to see what format it outputs.

Comment: also, upon further reading: `This property (TotalFreeSpace) indicates the total amount of free space available on the drive, not just what is available to the current user.`  It may in fact be a permissions issue that you'll have to discuss with your sysadmin.  other thoughts: perhaps run the program with elevated permissions (sudo it)?

Comment: Nop nothing worked... (root user) 
at the end i posted "df" to linux and parse the return table to get the correct value. (but thanks anyway)